# ViewDidLoad Not Called in UITabBar application

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate, viewdidload, uiwindow, viewwillappear

I am using Tabbar view controller as parent view controller. I am adding it from interface builder as shown in the below screen shot. Everything is working fine but the viewdidload,viewwillappear and viewdidappear methods are not calling from the begining. even if the viewcontroller is loading for the first time also. can any one please help me out code in my app delegate is

ScreenShot of IB: http://i58.tinypic.com/u4o6w.png

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
//[self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

I am able to see the loaded views but the methods are not calling.

Can any one please help me out

Comment: when using IB you may have to use awakeFromNib instead.

Comment: awakeFromNib, How to use that

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436895/init-and-awakefromnib) may help you