# How do you make a subclass of UITextField?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uitextfield

I am planning to subclass UITextField so I can customise the look and feel of textfields in my app globally. Based on the design in our mockups, textfields should have a green border which I already did for one of my textfields. (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5749376/334545)

I also changed placeholder color as said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19852763/334545

But all these are for just one textfield. I want all of my other textfields to have this so I tried subclassing by creating a new uitextfield class which I tried using. I added the methods above to `MYUITextField.m`'s initWithFrame method:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {
       // Initialization code
       UIColor *greenColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:122.0/255.0 green:168.0/255.0 blue:73.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
       UIColor *greyColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:87.0/255.0 green:87.0/255.0 blue:87.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

       self.layer.borderColor=[greenColor CGColor];
       self.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;

       self.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: greyColor}];

   }
   return self;
}
```

Should I just change the drawRect method? Will the app be slower because of it?

Comment: Are you concerned about the speed impact of overriding a drawrect? Then not likely. But generally, overriding drawRect is the last resort for Cocoa controls. I would advise to tinker with properties before changing the drawing mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using NIB, you need to tell the resource about your custom class.

Set the **Custom Class** to *MYUITextField* like so:

1. Select your TextField
2. Xcode > View > Utilities > Show Identity Inspector
3. In the Custom Class dropdown, pick your custom class

If using a resource, override `-awakeFromNib` instead of `-initWithFrame:`:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
    self.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                  initWithString:@""
                                      attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:
                                                   [UIColor greyColor]}];
}
```

See [init and awakeFromNib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436895/init-and-awakefromnib) for more details.

Comment: I also did this, but the changes (border color, placeholder color) aren't showing up. Do I need to do anything special like call redraw or something?

Comment: Yes. If using resource, override -awakeFromNib.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the way you are doing it will be more efficient. `-drawRect:` can be called multiple times. By setting the values in `-initWithFrame:` you only ensure these only get set once.

That being said I am pretty sure the performance difference will be negligible.

EDIT: This is if you're doing things programmatically. If using nibs or storyboards, use the method `-awakeFromNib`.

Comment: I've done that but sadly the textfilds arent reflecting the changes I made. Do I need to do something else? In my viewcontroller, I set the custom class to "MYUITextField" and also in the MyViewController.m file . (sorry new to ios)

Comment: Ah, didn't see you are using nibs.